# DB (MYSQL) command to query in c ++

Tags: c++, mysql, database

> ```
> sprintf_s(query, "update point set p%d=%d where hakbun='%d';", no, point, hakbun);
> ```

The data in the database is not output for the reason of the sentence.

What is the problem?

```
void updatePoint(MYSQL *con) {

    MYSQL * connection = NULL, conn;
    MYSQL_RES * sql_result;
    MYSQL_ROW sql_row;

    int hakbun, field, j, query_stat, no, point;
    char query[1024];

    cout << "student id > ";
    cin >> hakbun;

    cout << "            ┌────────────────────────────┐" << endl;
    cout << "            └────────────────────────────┘" << endl;
    cout << "              num > ";
    cin >> no;
    cout << "                              point > ";
    cin >> point;

    sprintf_s(query, "update point set p%d='%d' where hakbun='%d';", no, point, hakbun);
    sprintf_s(query, "select * from point where hakbun = '%d';", hakbun);
    cout << sizeof(query) << endl;
    query_stat = mysql_query(connection, query);
    sql_result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    while ((sql_row = mysql_fetch_row(sql_result)) != NULL) {
        void table();
        printf("  %s\t %s 　%s　　　%s　　%s　　%s\t%s\t%s\t %s\t%s\t%s\n", sql_row[0], sql_row[1], sql_row[2], sql_row[3], sql_row[4], sql_row[5], sql_row[6], sql_row[7], sql_row[8], sql_row[9], sql_row[10]);
    }
    mysql_free_result(sql_result);
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE` queries don't return any results. You need to use `SELECT` to fetch data from the database.

Comment: @Barmar But can not you update information with `SELECT`?

Comment: That's right. You need to do two queries. First you update, then you select to get the table contents.

Comment: The `UPDATE` query doesn't say which columns to return. What are you expecting to be in `sql_row[0]`, `sql_row[1]`, etc.?

Comment: @Barmar sprintf_s(query, "update point set p%d='%d' where hakbun='%d';", no, point, hakbun);
 sprintf_s(query, "select * from point where id = '%d';", hakbun);

Comment: @Barmar I `select` it after the `update`, but I do not get any results.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `where hakbun = '%d'`?

Comment: @Barmar Why is that a problem?

Comment: Because you're using different criteria in your `UPDATE` than in your `SELECT`, so you're not selecting the same rows you just updated.

Comment: If the student ID is in the `hakbun` column, why would you expect results when you look for it in the `id` column?

Comment: @Barmar This is because you need to enter the student ID (hakbun) and update the relevant information.

Comment: @Barmar p1, p2, ...etc This is a student-related information column.

Comment: So why are you using `WHERE id = '%d'` in your SELECT instead of `WHERE hakbun = '%d'`? When you did the update, you matched the user input to the `hakbun` column, so those are the rows that got updated, and those are the ones you should select.

Comment: @Barmar `WHERE id = '% id'`?
There is no field value named id.

Comment: You wrote in the comment: `sprintf_s(query, "select * from point where id = '%d';", hakbun);`

Comment: You're also missing an argument to `sprintf_s()`. The second argument should be `sizeof(query)`.

Comment: @Barmar sizeof(query) result : 1024

Comment: I know that. Read the documentation of `sprintf_s()`. It should be `sprintf_s(buffer, buffersize, formatstring, ...)`. You left out the `buffersize` argument.

Comment: Now you're not executing the `update` query.

Comment: @Barmar So should not `sprintf_s ()` be used for `update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the `update` query before you reassign `query` with the `select` query.

You're also missing the second argument to `sprintf_s()`, which should contain the size of the `query` buffer. And when you call `table()`, you shouldn't put `void` before that -- that makes it a function declaration, not a function call.

You're using the variable `connection` in your `mysql_query()` calls, but you never assigned that to a MySQL connection. Your function takes a connection as a parameter in `con`, you should use that instead.

```
sprintf_s(query, sizeof(query), "update point set p%d='%d' where hakbun='%d';", no, point, hakbun);
mysql_query(con, query);
sprintf_s(query, sizeof(query), "select * from point where hakbun = '%d';", hakbun);
mysql_query(con, query);
sql_result = mysql_store_result(con);
while ((sql_row = mysql_fetch_row(sql_result)) != NULL) {
    table();
    printf("  %s\t %s 　%s　　　%s　　%s　　%s\t%s\t%s\t %s\t%s\t%s\n", sql_row[0], sql_row[1], sql_row[2], sql_row[3], sql_row[4], sql_row[5], sql_row[6], sql_row[7], sql_row[8], sql_row[9], sql_row[10]);
}
mysql_free_result(sql_result);
```

Comment: There seems to be another cause.
Unfortunately, no results are available.

Comment: The `TABLE ()` function has only a `COUT` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the second `mysql_query()` call. Try it now.

Comment: It makes no difference what the `table()` function has. If you want to call it, you can't put `void` before it, that makes it a declaration, not a call. This is basic C++ syntax.

Comment: I don't know? Have you tried running the program under the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: `1> Point_Card.cpp (30): warning C4101: 'sql_row': This is an unreferenced local variable.`
`1> Point_Card.cpp (29): warning C4101: 'sql_result': This is an unreferenced local variable.`
`1> Point_Card.cpp (45): warning C4101: 'sql_row': This is an unreferenced local variable.`

I get this error, but the program is running.

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. Are those line numbers in this function?

Comment: In other functions, the query statement is printed well.

But that's only the `select` statement.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping the function in the debugger?

Comment: `0x00007FF9762149E7 (libmysql.dll) has an unhandled exception (of MySql_connect.exe). 0xC0000005: 0x00000000000004B0 An access violation occurred while reading the location.`

Comment: by windows local Debugger ..(?)

Comment: Which line is that happening on?

Comment: I do not know exactly which line.

`sprintf_s (query, sizeof (query), "update point set p%d = '%d' where hakbun = '% d';", no, point, hakbun);`

I think this sentence.

Photo attached.

Comment: Are you using a debugger? It should be able to tell you which line the error happened on. Where is the photo? I rejected your attempt to edit my answer. Put it in the question.

Comment: You never called `connection = mysql_connect(...);`.

Comment: If the `con` argument contains a MySQL connection, you should be using that instead of `connection`.

Comment: `connection = mysql_real_connect(&conn, host, user, pw, db, 3306, (char *)NULL, 0);` Is this sentens?

Comment: You don't need it, the function takes `MYSQL *con` as an argument. There's no need to open another question.

Comment: `MYSQL * conn` attempt to erase: program halted
`connection = mysql_real_connect (&conn, host, user, pw, db, 3306, (char *) NULL, 0);`
Insert sentence: Stop program first

Comment: I give up. You don't understand what you're doing, and can't even copy what I write. I said `con`, but for some reason you use `&conn`.

Comment: Oh! I just fixed it with `MYSQL * con` -> `MYSQL * conn`.